# WinRT HubSection Change Font on Hover

Tags: winrt-xaml

I'm playing around with the Hub App template for WinRT on Visual Studio right now and needed help with the styles.  When I open the HubPage.xaml, I see the Standard310x260ItemTemplate which is a grid that has an image and some text underneath it.  It cycles through all the items on the SampleData.json file.  I can change the text and the font, etc.  It seems to work fine.  What I can't figure out is how to make it change when my mouse hovers over it.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Standard310x260ItemTemplate">
        <Grid Height="250" Width="310" Margin="5,10,5,10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="150">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lesson1_text1}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" MaxHeight="60" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

By default, it changes the color of my text, but I don't see where the code is for that to happen.  I put up a snippet of the code, it's basically the one that comes with the template.  I was hoping to change the second TextBlock so that the words are italicized on a hover, instead of having the font color change.  This is probably incredibly simple, but I just can't find the code for it.

Thanks for reading through this!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that one of the simple ways to do it is to make a trigger.
You have to add a code below to your style `BodyTextBlockStyle`

Here is a code:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                        
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Also I recommend go to msdn and get know some information about [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I was doing some poking around, and it looks like VisualStateManager is the only option.  Style Triggers don't seem to be available to WinRT?

Comment: Sorry, it seems like triggers is not available for WinRt by default. (You can install some extension to get this functionality but it is a custom feature).
It is better to use `VisualStateManager `, you have to add `VisualState` with name `MouseEnter` and do what you want.
Like run some animation that could change `FontStyle` or `Background` color or text `Size` etc.